# Adjust the Camera Viewport Rect in Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, camera, unreal-4, unreal

Am new to Unreal Engine. I want to adjust the Camera Viewport  Rect so that the camera will render to half of the screen. This is achieved in Unity by changing the Camera Viewport Rect property. How can we achieve similar stuff Using Unreal Blueprint?